# What websites or services allow people type math equation and generate link to that equation?

Tags: math, markdown, mathjax

I'm looking for websites or services, where people can create math equation, then it will create a link to that equation, so i can put that link into my website to show the equation. Anyone knows something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Latex online tools, check this page for links :
http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/?cat=2

Comment: Wow, a long list, thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/equation.html?locale=default

write out the equation, it will generate the latex

Comment: it just generate the latex, but i want have a link too. Anyway thanks for answer :)

Comment: The 'solve with wolfram' button could be used as a permalink, by copying the link address (it will copy the formula too)

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com) works well for that.

For example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427euretnlv159

Comment: Thanks, i will check it, seems complex website :D

Answer (score 1):

If you really need images, you can get PNGs from the equation editor demo at [WIRIS](http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/demo/en/#image). The links to images are stable in my experience.

If you are looking beyond images there are pastebin-like sites like [MathBin](http://mathbin.heroku.com/) (which also provides embed code) and [MathB.in](http://mathb.in/), both powered by MathJax.

Comment: can i ask how long will images stored on web WIRIS?